# Java: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: java, mysql

I am using eclipse and mySQL for coding, while inserting the values I received the syntax error.

```
if(!(nameOfConvo.equals(visitorName))){
                    staffConvo = StringUtils.substringAfter(convo, ": ");
                    System.out.println("Staff - " + staffConvo);
                    String staffSql = "INSERT INTO webchatdata" + "(staffConvo)" + "VALUES ('"+ staffConvo+ "')";
                    myStat.executeUpdate(staffSql);
                }
                    else {
                        visitorConvo = StringUtils.substringAfter(convo, ": ");
                        System.out.println("Visitor - " + visitorConvo);
                        String visitorSql = "INSERT INTO webchatdata" + "(visitorConvo)" + "VALUES ('" +visitorConvo+"')";
                        myStat.executeUpdate(visitorSql);
                }
```

while in mySQL it is printing out some values, it'll only print halfway and display :

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's in a course that he has interest in, it is likely that he will excel in it.  I' at line 1
```

Inserting other variables into the database were fine like ex.

```
String timeStampSql = "INSERT INTO conversation" + "(timestamp)" + "VALUES ('" +timeStamp+"')";
            myStat.executeUpdate(timeStampSql);
```

Comment: A space is missing between `(timestamp)` and `VALUES` .

Comment: @Berger actually, that's the one he claims worked ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be with the content you're putting in to SQL.

Assuming the full string might be something like this.. *(You have not provided what the actual input is in this case, so I can only assume)*

`Bob's in a course that he has interest in, it is likely that he will excel in it.  I'm writing`

Notice that the first and last character are single quotation marks.

This is breaking your sql insert string, because it will close the string when it reads `'` in the text.

When you save the string, you need to escape the quotations so the string is not finished incorrectly. Note the backslashes added.

`Bob\'s in a course that he has interest in, it is likely that he will excel in it.  I\'m writing`